# Spring's couchbase JPA repository with abstract class fails to find entity

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

We are developing a project in Springboot that uses a Couchbase, I have following classes:

```
public abstract class Content {
    ...    
}

public class Film extends Content {
    ...
}
public class Serie extends Content {
    ...
}
```

Then I have following JPA repository:

```
public interface ContentJpaRepository extends ReactiveCouchbaseSortingRepository<Content> {
}
```

Then, when I save a content (film or serie) the content is successfully saved, however, the _class field gets the simple class name (instead of the full package name).
Then, when doing:

```
repository.findById(id);
```

The repository fails as it can't deserialize the json document to the expected entity. How could I achieve that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Using a generic repository is currently not supported for Couchbase Spring Data, as the _class attribute will refer to the abstract class instead of its implementations.